# how to connect remote svn using ssh tunnel in intellij

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want connect to a remote svn server through the remote server.
I understand I should be using a ssh tunnel. How can I achieve this? I tried this:

```
local - remote server - remote svn server
```

And set the subversion in my intellij 16.3 like this:

```
ssh tunnel : ssh -f id@(remote server ip) -L 22:(remote svn server ip):22 -N
```

The added a repository url like this

```
svn://(remote svn server ip)/location
```

But I somehow receive the following error. What can cause this and how to fix it?

> svn: E210003: connection refused by the server

Comment: Make sure you are getting success response by telnetting on 3690.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the server is reachable and you can open ssh session to it manually. See [Subversion through a tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005091/subversion-through-a-tunnel)

Make sure SVN integration in IntelliJ is configured to use svn command line client.

Make sure command line SVN client can access the server without issue